# arraylist seems to be empty out side the function

Tags: java, android, listview, layout

Hi i have an array list which is defined in the beginning of the class and i try too put objects inside it so that i can use it for a custom arrayAdapter for a listview but when i want to use it seems to be empty outside the response Listener i tested it with two Toasts forst one runs with no problem second one throws IndexOutOfBoundsException here's my code i have put comments beside those two Toasts they are in getUserGamesInfo function (sry for the mess that has happened to the code when i pasted it here that happened):

```
public class account_games_info extends Fragment {

HashMap<String, String> info = new HashMap<>();

String Playerscores, Rivalscore;
String[] array = null;
ListView listView;
ArrayList<gameHistory_object> scoreList=new ArrayList<gameHistory_object>;//*************
gameHistory_object gameHistory_object;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    get_user_games_ids();//a functio that calls getUserGamesInfo but i didnt bring it here 

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View games_info = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account_games_info, container, false);
    listView = (ListView) games_info.findViewById(R.id.listView);

    return games_info;
}

private void getUserGamesInfo(String gameID) {

    final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "username and password";
    SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME,
            MODE_PRIVATE);
    final String id = prefs.getString("userID", null);

    info.put("action", "sendGameInformation");
    info.put("userID", id);
    info.put("gameID", gameID);


    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(info);
    final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            url, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {

                gameHistory_object = new gameHistory_object();
                if (id.equals(response.getString("playerOneID"))) {

                    Playerscores = response.getString("playerOneTotalScore");
                    Rivalscore = response.getString("playerTwoTotalScore");

                    gameHistory_object.setRivalUsername(response.getString("playerTwoUsername"));
                    gameHistory_object.setPlayerScore(Playerscores);
                    gameHistory_object.setRivalScore(Rivalscore);

                } else {

                    Playerscores = response.getString("playerTwoTotalScore");
                    Rivalscore = response.getString("playerTwoTotalScore");

                    gameHistory_object.setRivalUsername(response.getString("playerOneUsername"));
                    gameHistory_object.setPlayerScore(Playerscores);
                    gameHistory_object.setRivalScore(Rivalscore);

                }
                   scoreList.add(gameHistory_object);
                 //first toast which runs with no problem     

                 Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"inside $$$"+scoreList.get(0).getRivalUsername(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (Playerscores.equals("")) {
                playerScore_view.setText("");
            } else {
                playerScore_view.setText(Playerscores);
                rivalScore_view.setText(Rivalscore);
            }

        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

     //second toast with outofboundexecption

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"outside 
      $$$"+scoreList.get(0).getRivalUsername(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
```

}

Comment: Please read: [How to create a **Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You never initialize your `scoreList` :

   ```
   ArrayList<gameHistory_object> scoreList;
   ```

   should be

   ```
   ArrayList<gameHistory_object> scoreList = new ArrayList();
   ```
2. You access the 0th item of your `scoreList` before it's been put there. The `JsonObjectRequest` you start is **asynchronous**. Your code will start the asynchronous request, then continue to the part where you try to make your toast, but the request has not yet ended (the `onResponse` part), thus your list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Your arraylist is not initialized any where in your code hence the IndexOutOfBoundsException.
Do this in your variable declaration:

`ArrayList<gameHistory_object> scoreList = new ArrayList <>();`